# I'm trying to make a fequency analysis programme using python but i'm having issues

Tags: python, frequency-analysis

At the moment I have made it so the programme can count the letter frequency in a given message but in the "descending_order" function It keeps saying LetterCountTuple isn't defined so it sort it, it won't print out the "new_letter_count", it won't reverse "new_letter_count" and it won't print out descending I thought I defined it in the function and in main, am I missing something? Can anyone help please! The code I have so far is this:

```
def main():
    message = input("please enter message")
    letterCount = getLetterCount(message)

    LetterCountTuple,new_letter_count,descending = descending_order(letterCount)


def getLetterCount(message):
    letterCount = {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 0, 'E': 0, 'F': 0, 'G': 0, 'H': 0, 'I': 0, 'J': 0, 'K': 0, 'L': 0, 'M': 0, 'N': 0, 'O': 0, 'P': 0, 'Q': 0, 'R': 0, 'S': 0, 'T': 0, 'U': 0, 'V': 0, 'W': 0, 'X': 0, 'Y': 0, 'Z': 0}
    for letter in message.upper():
        if letter in letterCount:
            letterCount[letter] += 1

    print(letterCount)
    return letterCount


def descending_order(letterCount):
    letterCountTuple = letterCount.items()
    new_letter_Count = LetterCountTuple.sort
    print(new_letter_Count)
    descending = reversed(new_letter_Count)
    print(descending)
    return new_letter_Count, descending

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple issues, descending_order returns two values so you are not going to be able to unpack three, you also never call sort `LetterCountTuple.sort`, you are missing parens `LetterCountTuple.sort()`.

`LetterCountTuple` is  defined in main not in `descending_order`, it should be letterCountTuple.

You also need `new_letter_Count = sorted(letterCountTuple)`, currently you are assigning `new_letter_Count` to `None`(if you actually call it) which is the return value from `.sort` as it is an inplace operation:

```
def descending_order(letterCount):
    letterCountTuple = letterCount.items()
    # create actual list of sorted letterCountTuple
    new_letter_Count = sorted(letterCountTuple)
    # reverse the list
    descending = new_letter_Count[::-1]
    # return three elements to unpack in main
    # LetterCountTuple,new_letter_count,descending = descending_order(letterCount)
    return letterCountTuple ,new_letter_Count, descending
```

I used `new_letter_Count[::-1]` to reverse the list as reversed is going to return a `listreverseiterator` object which you will have to call list on if you want to see the list so it is a bit redundant in this case.

On a side note, you should name your variables using underscores and lowercase letters `letter_count_tuple`,  `new_letter_count` etc..